# Setting a date to be empty by default

Tags: nodes, datetime

I have an event dates field that allows the user entering content to put in a start and and end date. By default it just shows them the start date. If they check a box it shows an end date and they can fill that out. So far so good.

However, I'm noticing that if they don't check the box and don't put in an end date it auto-sets the end date to be the same as the start date. This is not what I want. I want the result to be empty (mainly for Views so I can set it to not display if its empty).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this under the field settings for your date field.  If you edit your date field, you should see a "More Settings and Values" section:

[image]

You'll just have to set the default end date to "No default value"